# Can't able to play .mpeg video file on laptop using AForge c# framework. bug 'Video was stopped"

Tags: c#, aforge

1. In my c# application, I'm using Aforge framework to read `.mpeg` video files.
2. On the development server(windows server os), the application plays properly.
3. But on a different system with windows 10 os, it says " video was stopped" with the same video. 
   can you suggest me how to deal with this bug?